# Different result for plotting $\frac{x}{2}\tan\bigg(\log\bigg(\frac{2 (x^2 + y^2)}{5}\bigg)\bigg) = y$ by using Maple and Mathematica

Tags: plotting, maple

I want to plot the following equation

$$\frac{x}{2}\tan\bigg(\log\bigg(\frac{2 (x^2 + y^2)}{5}\bigg)\bigg) = y$$

I tried:

```
ContourPlot[x/2 Tan[Log[(2 (x^2 + y^2))/5]] == y, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},  
PlotPoints -> 150]
```

I also tried `MaxRecursion -> 6` but result is the same.

[image]

Then

I plot this equation by using *Maple18* , but result is different

```
with(plots, implicitplot)

implicitplot((1/2)*x*tan(log((1/5)*(2*(x^2+y^2)))) = y, x = -5 .. 5,
y =-5..5, numpoints = 1000, gridrefine = 6, color = red)
```

[image]

Comment: It is usually a good idea to indicate which version of Mathematica you are using.  I just tried this in version 11.0.1 on Windows and I get a plot very similar to Maple 18.

Comment: There is something funny going on here though,  a subsequent evaluation gave a plot like your first one.

Comment: @chuy on my machine (Mac OS X), version 10.3 yields a plot like in Maple, but version 11.0.1 yields OP's first plot.

Comment: No problems with first or subsequent evaluations, `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`: https://imgur.com/a/eaChp under `10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`.

Comment: I get the same plot as the OP, every time. Windows 7 x64, Mma 11.0.1

Comment: Interestingly it seems that `PerformanceGoal` might be causing this.   I had some other notebooks open and I think Dynamic Updating may have been disabled and this might have caused the `Automatic` setting for `PerformanceGoal` to be something like `"Speed"`.  Not sure

Comment: Judging from the comments, it might be a v11 issue.

Comment: Actually maple and mathematica 10 are getting it wrong by plotting spurious solutions where there are sign changes at singularities. there is no root near {-3.5,0} for example.  The extra circles are `x^2+y^2==5/2 Exp[n Pi/2]` for any integer `n`..

Comment: @george2079 To add to this, you can use `Exclusions -> None` to see the (correctly) missing circles. Moreover, you can run `Plot3D[x/2 Tan[Log[(2 (x^2 + y^2))/5]] - y, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 150, ClippingStyle -> None]` to see the circles Maple draws are extraneous.

Comment: we can also see the gaps in the v11 figure come from excluding the singular curves. I get that exact figure in 10.1 with `Exclusions -> Table[x^2 + y^2 == 5/2 Exp[k  Pi/2], {k, -5, 1, 2}]`.  How to fill the gaps is a good question.

Comment: I have a *Mathematica* 11 on Windows 10

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seeing $x^2+y^2$ and, implicitly, $y/x$ in the equation suggests using polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$ with $r \ge 0$.  After finding the solution with `Reduce` and seeing how it depends on an arbitrary integer `C[1]` and contains some point exclusions, we can simplify it:

```
f = Simplify[
   Reduce[x/2 Tan[Log[(2 (x^2 + y^2))/5]] == y /. {x -> r Cos[q], 
       y -> r Sin[q]} , {r}, Reals] /. C[1] -> n, 
   Assumptions -> Cos[q] != 0  && Sin[q] != 0 && r >= 0 && n ∈ Integers] ;
```

Half the solutions have negative signs, which is not appropriate for $r$, so let's get rid of them:

```
g = Union[Abs[List @@ f[[;; , 2]]]]
```

> $$\left\{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \sqrt{\exp \left(2 \Re\left(\pi  n+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{\cot ^2(q)+4}-\cot (q)\right)\right)\right)\right)}, \\ \sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \sqrt{\exp \left(2 \Re\left(\pi  n+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{\cot ^2(q)+4}-\cot (q)\right)\right)\right)\right)}\right\}$$

It plots up nicely.

```
Show[Table[
  PolarPlot[g, {q, -π, π}, Exclusions -> {0, π}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick], {n, 1, -2, -1}]]
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: So glad to see you posting again!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard there is a [different result](http://imgur.com/a/U8gwy) on my pc

Comment: I used version 9.0.1.0 for this example, FWIW.

Comment: Vito, one way to diagnose what might be going on with your PC is to try to make this plot in a different way.  For instance, this might work (it shows half of the plot, but you get the idea): `ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[
   Sqrt[5/2] Sqrt[E^(
    2 Re[n \[Pi] + ArcTan[1/2 (-Cot[q] - Sqrt[4 + Cot[q]^2])]])] {Cos[
      q], Sin[q]}, {n, 0, -2, -1}], {q, 0, \[Pi] }, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Thick]`